# INSERT OR REPLACE for sqlite rows with dependent foreign tables

Tags: android, sqlite

Say I have table Book and table Page. Say that table Page has book's dbId as a foreign key. When I do an `INSERT OR REPLACE` on a Book row, does that change the dbId of the book?

Say the book is `title="Song of Songs", author="King Solomon",pages=50"` say that I want to change the title of the book and that will lead to replacement of the row. So the question is: will the replace cause the dbId of the book to change? I imagine it shouldn't, but I just don't know.

So this is about ON CONFLICT REPLACE

Comment: Yes, REPLACE changes the ID. Why not use an UPDATE?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) says about INSERT OR REPLACE:

> When a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint violation occurs, the REPLACE algorithm deletes pre-existing rows that are causing the constraint violation prior to inserting the current row and the command continues executing normally.

If the new `dbId` has the same value as the old one, it does not change (obviously). But if the constraint violation happens in another column, the new `dbId` might have a different value (especially if it's an [autoincrementing](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) column).

Answer (score 0):

For implementing your idea :

1:) First get to foreign key from the first table using select query.

2:) then create a function with a parameter through which you can pass this foreign key in process of getting relevant data using the foreign key from the foreign table.

3:) Now use below query for fetching to related data using that key-

```
 databaseObject.update(TABLE_NAME, values, COLOMN_NAME + " = ?",
            Array_of_replacing_values);
```